# Remove TrackNumber of MP3's with TagLib

Tags: c#, forms, mp3, taglib

The only thing I can find is how to to remove all tags in a file, which is not what I want. Like this:

```
file.RemoveTags(TagLib.TagTypes.AllTags);
```

But how can I only remove only the TrackNumber?

Comment: call setTrack(0) is my guess.  Never used it, but that's what the docs say here: https://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Tag.html#a600ac6cc2e30d440d1258bf2431a8262

Comment: How should that be written exactly? I can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TagLib.File tag = TagLib.File.Create(@"File.mp3");
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag t = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tag.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);
t.Track = 0;
tag.Save();
```

Comment: EDIT: sets it to "0".

Comment: setting tag to 0 will effectively set the tag to nothing. try it. there's no other way of assigning a null value.

Comment: Hmmm, well the code gives a "0" as tracknumber for me... But what about setTrack(0) as you mentioned before? You didn't use it here, maybe that could do it? "If s is 0 then this value will be cleared" - sounds like my goal.

Comment: That was @RobertMcKee, not me. "well the code gives a "0" as tracknumber for me" - How do you check it? Using `t.Track` code?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realize it was another guy. Well I check it by opening the properties for the file in Windows, like this http://spunit.tk/x/scrn3550.png

Comment: I am using Win 8.1, I get nothing, not 0.